# Flutter easy loading ,how to change background color of easy loading?

Tags: flutter, package

I want to change background color of easy loading(package-flutter_easyloading) like by default it's black and I want to change it to red.
I have tried this code:

```
EasyLoadingStyle.custom;
EasyLoading.instance
     ..displayDuration =const Duration(milliseconds: 2000)
     ..backgroundColor = Colors.red
     ..indicatorColor = Colors.red
     ..maskColor = Colors.red
     ..userInteractions = false;
EasyLoading.show(status: 'Please wait...');
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal sample of code so that we can reproduce your problem

Comment: Please provide a proper description and example to understand the question better

Comment: @Lucie Thanks for your concern, but the problem has been solved.

Comment: @HaSnenTai Thanks for your concern, but the problem has been solved.

Comment: Perhaps you can answer your own question with explanation and code, in case someone else has trouble with the `EasyLoading` library

Comment: @Lucie In reference to your suggestion, I have posted the solution code for helping others.

Answer (score 1):

So I found out the solution for my problem:

Previous Code:

```
EasyLoadingStyle.custom;
EasyLoading.instance
     ..displayDuration =const Duration(milliseconds: 2000)
     ..backgroundColor = Colors.red
     ..indicatorColor = Colors.red
     ..maskColor = Colors.red
     ..userInteractions = false;
EasyLoading.show(status: 'Please wait...');
```

Solution code:

```
EasyLoading.instance
         ..displayDuration =const Duration(milliseconds: 2000)
         ..loadingStyle =EasyLoadingStyle.custom //This was missing in earlier code
         ..backgroundColor = Colors.red
         ..indicatorColor = Colors.red
         ..maskColor = Colors.red
         ..dismissOnTap = false;
         ..userInteractions = false;
    EasyLoading.show(status: 'Please wait...');
```